# About This Computer Always Says Install Updates

Tags: updates

Even after I click Install Updates, and it checks, it says "The software on this computer is up to date". But it never changes the button in "About This Computer" to "Up to Date". Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Where is this button "About This Computer"?

Comment: If I got your question right, then this button is never changed. Maybe a better text would be "Check for updates".

Comment: Select upper right menu button "About This Computer" and the settings panel comes up. There is a button in the lower right of this panel that either says "Install Updates" or "Up to Date". I have another computer right next to this one that I recently installed 16.04 on that correctly says "Up to Date". A 3rd computer, my main computer has been running Ubuntu for 8 years and updated to 16.04, but I've never seen this behavior before. I tried rebooting the problematic computer, but it still says "Install Updates".

Comment: Settings/About. But I've upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and I think the Install Updates button is no longer available here.